# Как правильно прописать RewriteRule в качестве редиректа?

Tags: apache

Есть такой конфиг на http://site1.com:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/catalog/name1(.*) https://site2.com/catalog/name1_modified/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site2.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ https://site2.com/ [R=301,L]
```

По задумке все неопределенные урлы старого сайта должны вести на главную нового.
Все определенные урлы на указанные страницы…

Но в любом случае переход идет всегда на главную.
Если я ввожу в браузере:
http://site1.com/catalog/name1/
должно перейти в данном случае на:
https://site2.com/catalog/name2_modified/
а ведет на:
https://site2.com/

Что не так? Куда смотреть?

Comment: смотрите в панель разработчика, отправляете запрос, увидите 301 на новый сайт. а потом небось еще один 301 от нового сайта с пересылкой на главную. зы: как по мне надо не правила реврайта на старом сайте писать, а перенаправить днс (если можно такое вообще) на новый сайт, а на нем уже написать правило для подхвата старых URL

Comment: зы: как по мне надо не правила реврайта на старом сайте писать, а перенаправить днс:

к сожалению нет доступа.
судя по панели разработчика двойного редиректа нет, сразу редиректит в корень нового сайта.

Comment: `/` в начале правила мб убрать? )